# FLASH - button[1] selection of "button1"

Tags: flash

Always wanted to know if this was possible, and how to do it, but I have no idea what to search for or what it's called.

Let me give you an example:

Lets say I've got 3 buttons.

"btn001"
"btn002"
"btn003"

If I want to add an eventlistener to these, is it possible to do it in a for loop (without having to put them to an array first). I want to do this so that I can add/remove buttons on my stage, and just update a variable telling me how many buttons there are.

For example like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<numBtns;i++){
    btn00[i].addEventListener(bla bla bla bla...);
}
```

Any ideas? =)

Answer (score 1):

Not as you have written them, but if you add them all to a common parent, you can loop over the children of the parent.